# Issue with Checkbox in JQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have painted a checkbox against each row in my datatable using the following function

```
"fnRender": function ( oObj ) {
        return '<input id="chkBox" name="chkBox" value="'+ oObj.aData[0] +'" type="checkbox" />'; }
```

In the onchange event I am changing the value of the checkbox to "Y", like this.

```
$('#myDataTable input:checkbox').live('change', function (event) {

                              if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                                    $(this).val("Y");                                       
                                }    

                            });
```

I have to now  check all those rows whose checkbox value is "Y" and submit the same. However on form submit when I try to retrive the values of the checkboxes against each `tr` , like this

```
$('#myDataTable tr').each(function() {                                                        
                      var aData = oTable.fnGetData(this);
```

The array returned by fnGetData does not contain the updated value of the checkbox.

However when I evaulate the value of `this` passed as a parameter to `fnGetData` in Firebug , it shows the updated value of the checkbox.

I am unable to understand this behaviour of fnGetData , why does it not show me the updated value of the checkbox

Can anybody please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the root cause of the issue.

The fnGetData was being called as `oTable.fnGetData()` , and `oTable` was equal to the initial datatable that I had painted.

hence whenever I was calling the `fnGetData()` , it would return the original value of the Datatables

I am now looping over each `tr` and getting the current value.